# Get HTML Source of temporary drag & drop element

Tags: drag-and-drop, web-inspector

I have this page I can only access in the browser. There is a HTML element that only exists during drag&drop, and I want to get / analyze its HTML code in the Inspector / Firebug.. but as soon as I stop dragging, the element is removed.
Is there any way of getting the generated HTML element without wading through the JS source that builds it?

EDIT: got it, using the ctrl+S shortcut in chrome to save the page while holding mouseDown with the dragged-element did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug html inspection shows the HTML of the page real time, so it does show changes caused by interaction. The trick is probably to scroll the inspection panel to the section of the HTML where your drag element appears. That way you would be able to see it while you drag.

Comment: As does Chromes's, but then I can only see the outer (div-) container. I want to expand the container and look at the children inside, so I have to click it and let go of the dragging. In that moment, the element disappears. Unfortunately, real time JS-editing (as for CSS) is not possible, so I can't prevent the removal of the element.